# MySQL query on multiple tables

Tags: mysql

Greets! I have 12 tables, one for each month of the year:

```
January

+----+-----+  
| id | sale|  
+----+-----+  
|  1 | 250 |  
|  3 | 500 |
|  5 | 200 |  
|  7 | 100 |  
+----+-----+

February

+----+-----+  
| id | sale|  
+----+-----+  
|  1 | 350 |  
|  2 | 400 |
|  3 | 500 |  
|  4 | 800 |  
+----+-----+
```

etc.

I need to do a query where the result is something like this:

```
Annual Sales
+----+-----------+-----------+
| id | Sales_Jan | Sales_Feb |
+----+-----------+-----------+
|  1 |       250 |       350 |
|  2 |         0 |       400 |
|  3 |       500 |       500 |
|  4 |         0 |       800 |
|  5 |       200 |         0 |
|  7 |       100 |         0 |
+----+-----------+-----------+
```

Where the matching ids from both tables do not duplicate and the missing ids from other months are shown by putting a 0 or any other symbol indicating that there was not any sales that month from that id.

Thank you very much!

Comment: next time make a months table and reference them with month_id

Comment: Agreed!  I am not sure why you are storing your sales in separate database tables for each month, but it generally flies in the face of entity design and data modeling.  A sale is a sale, the month it occurs in is an attribute of a sale.  Tables should represent entities, not attributes.

Comment: I know, is part of the engineering process, but the database was handed to me like that and I do not have permission to modify it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can approach this using `union all` and aggregation:

```
select id,
       sum(case when month = 'Jan' then sale else 0 end) as Jan_Sale,
       sum(case when month = 'Feb' then sale else 0 end) as Feb_Sale,
       . . .
       sum(case when month = 'Dec' then sale else 0 end) as Dec_Sale
from ((select 'Jan' as month, id, sale from January) union all
      (select 'Feb' as month, id, sale from February) union all
      . . .
      (select 'Dec' as month, id, sale from February)
     ) t
group by id;
```

Comment: You are a saint! Thank you very much! There's a missing "as" before the t, but i do not know if I have to edit that or you. I'm new around, as you can see. Again, thank you very much.

Comment: @user3063952 . . . I use `as` for column aliases but not for table aliases.  This is the standard for Oracle, although the `as` is usually optional for most database engines.

Comment: By any chance, would you know how to this same thing on Ms-access? I was told that the php is with MySQL, but there's gonna be a console application with Ms-access. Thank you in advance.

Comment: @user3063952 . . . MS Access uses `iif()` instead of `case`.  I think the `union all` will work there.